# Python 3 - How to load (read) only the specific value from a big JSON file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a big JSON file. Imagine the JSON file contains something like this:

```
{
  "key_1": "some value",
  "key_2": "I want this value",
  "key_3": [
    "OMG_THIS_IS_HUGE_DATA"
  ],
  "key_4": "that's what she... Nvm..."
}
```

I want to extract and load only the value of `key_2` which is `I want this value`. I don't need the rest of the data to be read or take a huge amount of memory space. How can I only get the value of `key_2` without reading (loading) the rest of the JSON file? (Especially the `key_3` with value `OMG_THIS_IS_HUGE_DATA`

PS: I've seen really close questions/answers but I couldn't find a solution for my specific problem yet. Sorry if this is a duplicate question.

Comment: There are many similar questions, though I have yet to find a good duplicate. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32661888/874188 for a solution with proper partial reading.

Comment: I tried the ijson already but unfortunately, I couldn't make it work for my example. My example doesn't have a broader key (main key?) as their example documented in the ijson documentation. But I will look into it again.

Comment: Huh? `print(list(ijson.items(open('/tmp/ijson.json'), 'key_2'))[0])` produces `I want this value`

Comment: @tripleee could you please give this as an answer so I can select it as the correct answer. My JSON had a slightly different structure and I didn't realize at the time of writing my question. This works, thanks.